# WP_Customize_Image_Control and selecting from library?

Tags: customization, images

I am adding some theme options, one of which is an image option.

```
 $wp_customize->add_control(
            new WP_Customize_Image_Control(
                $wp_customize,
                'theme_ppr_options[portfolio_photo]',
                array(
                    'label'      => __( 'Upload a portfolio', 'ppr' ),
                    'section'    => 'mytheme_options',
                    'settings'   => 'theme_ppr_options[portfolio_photo]',
                    'context'    => 'your_setting_context' 
                )
            )
        );
```

But i notice i am not able to select an image from the library, how can this be enabled??

regards

Comment: This might help you

http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/59904/custom-image-size-not-selectable-in-uploader?rq=1

Comment: This isn't helpful for me at all. This link requests that php_g2 is enabled, and this will make the selection of existing images work, but I'm using WAMP, and the extension is enabled, but I still only have the option of uploading new files from my computer, and not selecting them from the media library. Any extra info?